# Accurate use / consumption of the HMVC pattern?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, hmvc

I am trying to understand HMVC and how or if I should consider it in my current MVC app.

Regarding this quote from [this][1] question about MVC architecture,

> Sometimes the Hierarchical-Model-View-Controller (HMVC) pattern (aka
>   Presentation-Abstraction-Control) is a good choice for dealing with
>   more complex interface and application demands.
>
> "However, the traditional MVC scope falls short when it comes to the
>   control of GUI elements (widgets). MVC does not handle the
>   complexities of data management, event management, and application
>   flows. As an adaptation of the MVC triad, the HMVC --
>   Hierarchical-Model-View-Controller -- paradigm seeks to redress some
>   of the above-mentioned issues."
>
> Jason Cai, Ranjit Kapila, and Gaurav Pal (July 2000). "HMVC: The
>   layered pattern for developing strong client tiers". JavaWorld
>   Magazine.
>
> [1]:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113602/when-to-use-mvc-architecture

I have been trying to understand PAC/HMVC, and the above text struck a chord.  The triad abstraction of HMVC can be applied to "widgets" on a page, or how in using the ASP.Net view engine (vs the Razor view engine), would translate to "controls" on the page.

Would that be an accurate application of the HMVC pattern?

If so, I'm not sure exactly how that would be implemented.  I do see the advantages of this, in that if the main page loads fine, and some of the user controls/widgets error-out, the page still loads.

So the main page controller would make the call to its widgets controllers?  From the main view, I am guessing that model inheritance would come into play, just as you would consume the model's objects in the view of a simple MVC page.

What would that look like in code - calling the model data from say two or three triads down the chain from a top-level view?

Comment: What is "ASP.Net visual engine"?

Comment: Updated... ASP.Net view engine vs another one, like the Razor view engine used by MVC3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading different resources of HMVC, I believe ASP.NET MVC does have HMVC since v2.0 in the form of **Areas**.

Couple that with **T4MVC** and calling Action.PartialX() methods and you've got yourself the next buzz-word **HMVC**.

Comment: The idea of HMVC is that a coming request is redirected to the appropriate controller down the pipe. ASP.NET MVC has only one controller managing a request so it doesn't fit into HMVC description.

Comment: Huh? "ASP.NET MVC has only one controller managing a request"

You can route the request to the appropriate controller right from the beginning using Route Tables along with Areas

Comment: Routing a request to a controller has nothing to do with routing a request to a chain of controllers.

Comment: Can you elaborate please the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you raise some interesting points. Secondly, I am making the assumption you are familiar with the ASP.NET MVC Framework.

Just thinking out loud here, there is a HtmlHelper called Partial(), which takes a controller and action and returns the result. So, if you write an Action that returns a PartialView (which could be used a widgets - you can have multiple per page), could this be a plausible implementation of the architecture above?

Thanks,

Matt